# PHP $_POST and variables

Tags: php, post

Hey Ya'll I have a question (sorry dont have code, but i'll try my best explaining) I have an input text field with a value in it....that value goes into a variable...

```
$amount = $_POST['amount']
```

So in this form if something is missing and the user gets an error message (something didn't match up or invalid information) I would like the variable $amount put back into the input text field...is this possible?

Sorry for lack of details, but I have no idea how to code this.

Thanks

Comment: I have echoed out the variable $amount after the form gets submitted and its coming back with the right data, just need to know how to put that variable into the form.

Comment: 9 question and 0 accepts? Really? It's that little green tick icon - and people will be a lot more willing to help you if you use it more often...

Comment: You also have to end your line with a semicolon: `$amount = $_POST['amount'];`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this:

```
<input type="text" size="25" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
```

Be sure the user can't inject HTML back onto the page, as that could cause issues.  Typecasting `$amount` to an integer might be appropriate in this case.  Two solutions could be:

```
$amount = (int) $_POST['amount'];
```

```
$amount = htmlentities($_POST['amount']);
```

Comment: Also make sure to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) so bad input doesn't end up breaking the HTML, or allowing XSS or something.

Comment: I'd recommend `htmlentities($_POST['amount'])` rather than just `$_POST['amount']` -- keeps chars like quotes, ampersands etc from screwing with the HTML.

Comment: I often work in a bilingual environment so I'd just like to add that `htmlentities` needs you to mention the encoding as one of its parameters if you want it to work correctly.

Comment: this is what is already in the value number_format(htmlentities($invoiceArray[0]["remainingbalance"]),2, ".", "")

Comment: can't I do $invoiceArray[0]["remainingbalance"] = $amount